# Audio files not Playing in Blackberry

Tags: audio, blackberry, java-me, mmapi

I'm trying to play a recorded wave file. While playing, an exception is thrown at the following statement:

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");
```

My entire code for playing the wave file is as follows:

```
if (types[cnt].equals("audio/x-wav")) {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("RecordAudio");
    InputStream is =  
        clazz.getResourceAsStream("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/original.wav");
    //create an instance of the player from the InputStream
    Player player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");
    player.realize();
    player.prefetch();
    //start the player
    player.start();
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: itsteju, it would be helpful if you would give more info in questions (rim os version, bb model) and if you would format your code. thanks!

Comment: Hello Coldice, sorry for bad formatting of code. Im using BB Pearl 8100 device with o.s.version 4.5.0.81

Comment: Thanks Marc for formatting code ...

Answer (score 7):

The function getResourceAsStream is for pulling resources from a JAR/COD file, not from the filesystem.  Plus, this is simpler than you are making it. Just pass the file name and path to createPlayer, like so:

```
try {
    String filename = "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/original.wav";
    Player player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.Manager.createPlayer( filename );
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error creating player");
} catch (MediaException e) {
    System.out.println("Error media type");
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried with above code, No exception is thrown...but media player is not activated.Debugger console prints something as: MN: getPlayableStreams0(0)=1
MN: getLength0(0)=0
MN: getPlayableStreams0(0)=1
MN: isSeekable0(0)=1
AR: add source 10
AR: setAudioMode 32
MN: play0(0) is audio, NO check for active pause
MN: play0(0)=0
MN: MEDIA_STOPPED received
MN: handle=0 staticsHandle=7fffffff
AUDIOMANAGER: IOException
MN: unload0(0)=2 pauseHandle=7fffffff
AR: remove source 10
AR: setAudioMode 32

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is because of wrong MIME type. Try this:

```
String fileName = "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/original.wav";
String mimeType = "audio/x-wav";
String types[] = javax.microedition.media.Manager
        .getSupportedContentTypes(null);
for (int cnt = types.length - 1; cnt >= 0; --cnt) {
    if (types[cnt].equals(mimeType)) {
        InputStream is = null;
        FileConnection fconn = null;
        try {
            fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(
            fileName, Connector.READ);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file");
        }
        try {
            is = fconn.openInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening stream");
        }
        Player player = null;
        try {
            player =                    
            javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(
            is, mimeType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error creating player");
        } catch (MediaException e) {
            System.out.println("Error media type");
        }
        try {
            player.realize();
        } catch (MediaException e) {
            System.out.println("Player cannot be released");
        }
        try {
            player.prefetch();
        } catch (MediaException e) {
            System.out.println("Player cannot be prefetched");
        }
        // start the player
        try {
            player.start();
        } catch (MediaException e) {
            System.out.println("Player cannot be started");
        }
    }
}
```

Also see in console what kind of exception was thrown.

Comment: execution stopped at:
InputStream is = clazz
                .getResourceAsStream(
        "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/original.wav");

Comment: On debugger console,FRIDG: could not find file:/SDCard/BlackBerry/original.wav is displayed.
But the file exists at specified location.I also tried playing other files, none of them are being played...Please help.

Comment: updated according to Fostah answer. and don't forget to simulate SD Card ;)